# SQL - order by status

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I wrote sql for ordering but I want to add that first odreding clause be by ACTIVE/INACTIVE status (first active than inactive).

My code:

```
public function getUsers()
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user 
            WHERE roles::text NOT LIKE '%ADMIN%' 
            AND status != 'DELETED'
            ORDER BY first_name ASC;";
    return $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->query($sql)->fetchAll();
}
```

I have to constants

```
const STATUS_ACTIVE = 'ACTIVE';
const STATUS_INACTIVE = 'INACTIVE';
const STATUS_INVITED = 'INVITED';
const STATUS_DELETED = 'DELETED';
```

and I want for the to be added to ORDER BY but I dont know how to fit them.

I am new at sql.. Can anyone help?

Comment: Since `A` comes before `I`, you can simply do `ORDER BY status, first_name`. If you get more statuses, for example `PENDING`, that should be between those, you can use `FIELD()` to sort it in a custom order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify multiple expressions in the ORDER BY clause separated by commas.

In your case:

```
SELECT * FROM user 
            WHERE roles::text NOT LIKE '%ADMIN%' 
            AND status != 'DELETED'
            ORDER BY status ASC, first_name ASC;
```

This works by first ordering all result rows by the status field, then ordering them by first_name.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a second sort level by the `status`:

```
ORDER BY
    status,
    first_name;
```

This should work because `ACTIVE` is alphabetically before `INACTIVE`.  A safer way to do this on MySQL would be to order by `FIELD`:

```
ORDER BY
    FIELD(status, 'INACTIVE', 'ACTIVE') DESC,
    first_name
```

This would put active before inactive, followed by all other status values, including null, last.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your code is PHP you can define a status variable and use it parametrically in your sql query:

`$status = STATUS_VARIABLE;`
`$sql = "SELECT * FROM user`
           `WHERE roles::text NOT LIKE '%ADMIN%'`
            `AND status != 'DELETED'`
            `ORDER BY first_name,". $status ." ASC;";`